# Can I (or should I) use the 7-1 pattern with SASS in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, sass

I would like to use some good patterns in React development (for styles). As far as I can see it, React.js encapsulates the styles for components (if I understand it correctly).

Can/should I use the 7-1 pattern (using the `shame.scss` file of course)?
If not, what is the best practice you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, there are many valid patterns to style React components.

From the top of my mind are:
7-1 scss pattern, css (or sass) modules, styled components and their combinations.

7-1 pattern can work like a charm - just import the main scss file once in the top level component, and you're set.

As long as you don't mix patterns, the code should be organized and highly scalable.

Once you start mixing concepts, you may end up being confused whether you should have isolated components with their styles in CSS modules (ex: Button component with css modules) or keep component styles as part of your 7-1 pattern.

In my experience the best decision to make is to stick to one end.